# How to add designmode dummy data into WPF control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Added entity Dummy to the usercontrol resources but Visual Studio complains it can't find resource 'Dummy'. Is it possible to add design data this way? What am I doing wrong?

```
<UserControl x:Class="MovieScraper.Media"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:entity="clr-namespace:Processor.Entity;assembly=Processor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Dummy}"
        d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="White">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <entity:Media x:Key="Dummy" Title="Akira"></entity:Media>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Have a look at MVVMLight and how it approaches this problem. http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'm using Galasoft's MVVM Light Toolkit, could you be more specific?

Comment: In that case you should just double check that you follow the binding example correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to bind d:DataContext to resource Dummy, but you are missing the keyword **Binding**. Please change this line to

```
d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Dummy}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would create a MockDataContext model. This works pretty nice. This is a snippet from code that I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Modules.Core.Views.HeaderView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Modules.Core.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="1024">
    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MockHeaderViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Big advantage is that you can actually run some code. For example I use it to update the time in my header in design time and vary some fields. You can immediately see if your binding work and your layout is giving you components enough space.

Comment: I've got a pretty simple control mostly displaying data, but this is good stuff. Will try it out on the more complex controls i'm using.

Comment: I love this. Being able to set a design time-only view model for xaml is great. Thanks!